# .DS_Store file is in .gitignore, but it keeps popping up in status

Tags: git, gitignore

I searched..I read all the answers on similar or even the same questions that I could find  here. I watched tutorials. It seems super easy and logical when it's happening in somebody's terminal. In mine, it's just not working. Apparently,I must be missing something super obvious.
I commited .gitignore, but .DS_Store still appears in status. Then I deleted .DS_Store using git rm --cached .DS_Store (just in case, even though It wasnt in my repo).
Nope. Now I'm seeing it appearing in staging area as "changes to be commited => deleted: .DS_Store".
Is there a way to get rid of it completely? So it stops popping up in my status?

Here it is:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    .DS_Store

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   README.md
        modified:   assets/.DS_Store
        modified:   assets/stylesheets/main.css
        modified:   index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (rather mild) problem here is that you have some number of *existing* commits in which `.DS_Store` exists.  Note that the current status indicates at least two such files, one in the top level of the tree and one in `assets`:

> ```
> deleted:    .DS_Store
> modified:   assets/.DS_Store
> ```

**These existing commits cannot be changed**.  They will continue to hold a copy of the `.DS_Store` file forever (or as long as these commits continue to exist, anyway).

You *must* delete these `.DS_Store` files (**all of them**) from Git's index if you wish them *not* to be stored in future commits.  By doing that—running `git rm --cached` and making a commit—you're telling Git that when you check out one of these historical commits, it should extract the historical `.DS_Store` files, and when you switch from that historical commit to one of the more modern commits that *lacks* these `.DS_Store` files, Git should *remove* them.

Since macOS Finder will, if the file is missing, create a new `.DS_Store` whenever it shows the directory in a Finder window, this particular action is safe enough in *this particular case*.  However, there are several things to be aware of that can make this trickier for *other* files, should you need to use `git rm --cached` on them as well.

## Optional reading: why it's this complicated

Git's *index*, which has this relatively poor name (index? what is it index-ing?), has two other names.  Git also calls this thing the *staging area*, which refers to how you use it, and the *cache*, which refers to how it's used internally.  The name "cache" mostly shows up in the spelling of `git rm --cached`, which tells Git to remove it from the index without also removing it from your working tree.

Okay, so we have three names for the thing.  What does that tell us?  Well, for one thing, it tells us that Git's index is *really important*.  In fact, it's absolutely crucial.  But why?  Why does Git insist on shoving its index in our faces over and over again?  Ultimately, the real answer to *that* question is just "it was a deliberate choice"—but it's worth looking at the factors that made Linus Torvalds make this choice.  This turns out to start with *commits*.

Git is, in the end, all about commits.  It's not about *files*, although files are, in a sense, contained within each commit.  It's not about *branch names* either, although branch names are necessary to help you (and Git) *find* the commits.  The commits, though, *are* the history in the repository.  They hold the files, and they form things that we sometimes call branches (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)).

Each commit is numbered, by a big ugly hash ID number.  Each commit stores two things:

- a snapshot of all of the files that Git knew about, at the time you (or whoever) *made* the commit; and
- *metadata*, or information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why (your log message).

Inside the metadata for a commit, each commit holds the hash ID of some *earlier* commit, and this is what makes commits act as history.  We won't get into the details here but this is how branches actually work.

The crucial bit to know here is that **no part of any commit can ever be changed**.  This is because the hash ID *of* the commit is a checksum of all of the data *in* the commit.  Git computes these checksums when making the commits, and verifies them when extracting the commits.  If they don't match, the commit has somehow become corrupt in storage,<sup>1</sup> and cannot be used.

So, all the files stored *in* a commit are read-only.  They are also compressed (to save space) and de-duplicated (to save space and time).  If two commits in a row share 999 out of 1000 files, they *literally* share the files: only the one *changed* file has to go into storage for the later commit.  But this means that the *committed* files are entirely useless for getting any new work done:

- you can't change them, and
- most programs can't even *read* them.

So Git *has* to extract commits to a usable area.  Git calls this area your *working tree* or *work-tree*, because it's where you do your work.  The files in here are ordinary everyday files, and you can get work done.

What Git needs, then—and this is common across all version control systems; they all share this kind of setup—is:

- committed, unchanging *historical* files; and
- a work area (workspace or working tree or whatever you like) where you get work done.

In Git's case, the work area is literally *yours*, to do with as you will.  This means you can create files in it that you *don't* want Git to save-for-all-time.  This, you might assume, is where `.gitignore` comes in.  This assumption isn't *wrong*, but it's *incomplete*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Storage media *do* fail, in the real world.  Most failures are detected, but there is a chance—usually claimed to be about 1 in 10<sup>16</sup> or better—that some failure might be missed, giving you back bad data.  Google have done analyses and found that the actual error rate tends to be higher than claimed.

---

#### The index

What Git really needs is a *list of files to commit*.  That is, suppose you're in your work-tree, doing your work.  You create a bunch of files—maybe several hundreds, or thousands, or whatever.  *Two* of those files should go into the *next* commit as new files, and the rest should be ignored.

One possible way to deal with this is to just have an "ignore these files" file, and automatically generate the list of files-to-be-committed from every file that's not listed in the "ignore these files" file.  But if you try this out, you'll find it is error-prone.  Git and several similar version control systems use, instead, an explicit "add some file(s)" command to *add* them to a list of files.

The index, then, *could* have been just a sort of manifest: *these are the files to include; all other files are to be called out as untracked when you ask for status*.  Suppose this were the case, and you said *add all files*.  You hadn't told Git explicitly to *ignore* the `.DS_Store` files.  They go into the list.  You make a commit, and the commit has the `.DS_Store` files.  Later, you realize that you didn't *intend* to commit the `.DS_Store` files.

It's too late.  Those commits now exist.  No matter what you do to the manifest, at most, you're just going to omit the `.DS_Store` files from *future* commits.  You can't fix existing commits as they are read-only.  At best, you can go back to all your old commits, take them out one by one, remove the `.DS_Store` files, and make a *new and improved* commit that's otherwise the same as the original, but now lacks the `.DS_Store` files.

(You can in fact do all this.  But it means that you need to get *everyone else*—all the other people that have a clone of your repository—to stop using the old commits in favor of the new and improved ones.)

Now, what makes Git's index particularly unusual—as compared to, e.g., Mercurial's manifest—is that having this list of files, Linus decided to *expose* it, and to do a couple of special tricks with it:

- The index holds not only the names of all the files that go into the next commit—initially, populated by extracting whichever commit you `git checkout`—but also the internal Git *blob hash ID* of each such file.
- During merges, the index *expands* to hold up to three files at a time, all of which have the same *name*.
- The `git commit` command *doesn't bother to look at your work-tree.*<sup>2</sup>  Instead, it just packages up whatever is *in* the index, at the time you run `git commit`.  This is very fast, because those internal blob hash IDs are how Git stores the files: in fact, they're already there, pre-compressed and pre-de-duplicated.
- The `git add` command amounts to: *compress and de-duplicate these files and put them in your index, replacing any previous file of the same name, or creating a new entry if there is no previous file*.<sup>3</sup>
- The `git rm` command means *remove the file from both your index and my work-tree*.  Adding `--cached` means *leave my work-tree copy alone*.

One outcome of all of this is that `git commit` won't commit what's in your *work-tree*.  You can use this property to fuss with files in your work-tree for testing purposes, without actually committing the test code.  This can be good or bad; different people have different opinions about whether it's more often good or more often bad; but that's how Linus chose to do it, and that behavior is now embedded in the hearts and minds of many Git users.

What this all boils down to is a relatively simple statement: *The index holds, at all times, your **proposed next commit**, or else holds merge conflicts that are yet to be resolved so that a commit is not currently possible.*  If we omit the merge conflict case, you can just think of the index as holding your proposed next commit.

When checking out some existing commit, Git populates its index *from* that commit, then uses the populated index to fill in your work-tree with files.  This means that Git is now ready to make a *new* commit, that would exactly match the current commit.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>For usability, this long ago got changed a bit: `git commit` now runs `git status` internally, and produces a commented-out `git status` section in the commit message you can edit.

<sup>3</sup>In fact, `git add` can also mean *make the index match* to the extent that if you *remove* a work-tree file, `git add` can remove the index copy of that file.  For instance: `rm path/to/file; git add path/to/file` is a long-winded way of running `git rm path/to/file`.

<sup>4</sup>If the index and current commit *do* match, `git commit` will typically refuse to make a new commit, forcing you to use `git commit --allow-empty` to make the commit.  The new commit isn't *empty*—it has whatever is in the index—but the *difference* from the current commit will be empty.

---

#### Summary so far

Git doesn't make a new commit from your working tree, and therefore the contents of your `.gitignore` file are irrelevant to the `git commit` command.  Instead, Git makes a new commit from whatever is in Git's index.  The contents of Git's index index are normally from the *current* commit.<sup>5</sup>

Once you've added some file, then, the file *keeps going into new commits* until you explicitly *remove* it.  That's true regardless of the file's name being, or not being, in a `.gitignore` file.  To make the file really go away, you *must* remove it.  Then the difference between the current commit and the next commit you make will include literally *removing* the file.

So: What *does* listing file names, or directory names, or patterns, or anything that you can list in `.gitignore` files, in a `.gitignore` do?  What good is it?

---

<sup>5</sup>There are some exceptions to this rule; see, e.g., [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

---

#### What `.gitignore` does

There are two useful things that `.gitignore` (or any other exclusion file such as `.git/info/exclude`) does, and one kind of dangerous thing:

- First, there are en-masse `git add` operations, such as `git add --all` or `git add .` or `git add *`.<sup>6</sup>  Or, for that matter, you could list a file pattern like `*.pyc` in `.gitignore` and then run `git add file.pyc` anyway.  What happens here is simple: *If the file isn't already in Git's index, and the name is in an exclusion file, `git add` doesn't add it.*

  This means that if a file is currently *untracked*—see below for the definition of untracked—it stays untracked.  But if the file is already in Git's index, the `.gitignore` entry *has no effect*.
- Second, when you run `git status`, Git will often whine about various files being untracked.  Listing the name or pattern in an exclusion file *stops the whining*.

We'll get to the dangerous thing in a moment.  Let's define *tracked* now.  **A tracked file, in Git, is a file that is currently in Git's index.**  That's it.  It's really that simple.  If a file in your work-tree is in Git's index *right now*, it is tracked.  If it is not in Git's index *right now*, it is untracked.

Remember that Git's index contents change!  If you `git checkout` some commit, Git fills in its index.  Those files are now tracked.  If you run `git add` on a new file, that file goes into Git's index.  That file is now tracked.  If you run `git rm`—with or without `--cached`—on a file, that file comes *out* of Git's index.  That file is now *untracked*.  Of course, if you ran `git rm` without `--cached`, that file is gone from your work-tree too.<sup>7</sup>

What `git status` does, among other things like print out the name of your current branch, is run *two* `git diff` commands:

- The first `git diff` compares the *current commit* to Git's index.  For every file that is the same, Git says nothing.  For every file that's *different*, or new or removed, Git says that the file is *staged for commit*, along with being modified, added, or deleted.
- The second `git diff` compares what's in Git's index to what is in your work-tree.  For every file that is the same, Git says nothing.  For files that are *different*, Git says the file is *not staged for commit*.  What's a bit unusual here is that for files that are *new*, Git calls these files *untracked*.
  That last bit, of course, is because of the definition of an untracked file.

Listing a file in `.gitignore` makes `git status` *shut up* about untracked-ness.  It doesn't have any effect on the actual tracked-ness at all!  It just shuts up the whining.

The last thing that listing a file name or pattern in `.gitignore` (or some other exclusion file) does is where things are a tiny bit dangerous.  This gives Git permission to *destroy* such a file:

- Suppose you're on commit `a123456...`, which *doesn't* have a `.DS_Store` file in it, and there is a `.DS_Store` file in your work-tree.  That is, `.DS_Store` is currently *untracked*.
- You now issue a `git checkout` command to check out commit `4321cab...`, which *does* have a `.DS_Store` file in it.

To extract commit `4321cab...`, Git will have to put a `.DS_Store` file into Git's index, and then copy that file out into your work-tree.  You already have a `.DS_Store` file in your work-tree.  This file will be overwritten.

Normally, Git will stop and complain: *Hey, if I extract commit `4321cab...`, I'll destroy your `.DS_Store` file!*  This gives you a chance to move it out of the way, if it's precious data.  But if you list the file as *ignorable*, Git will feel free to clobber it.

Since the data in a `.DS_Store` is rarely considered precious, this is probably OK here.  But be careful in general.

---

<sup>6</sup>The precise action of the `*` in a Git command depends on whether you're using a Unix-style shell such as `bash`, or a DOS-style command-interpreter such as `CMD.EXE`, but Git itself does glob expansion, so it comes out pretty similarly.  There are subtle differences we won't cover here though.

<sup>7</sup>Exercises with a bit of philosophical bent: if the file named `ghost` *isn't* in your work-tree and isn't in Git's index, is the non-existent `ghost` file also untracked?  (It is not in Git's index, so it won't be in the next commit, anyway.)  What about a file named `ghost` that *is* in Git's index, but isn't in your work-tree?  Is this file tracked?  Will it be in the next commit?